# Comparator isn't being called

Tags: android

```
List<UserContribution> userContributions = new ArrayList<>();
...
Collections.sort(userContributions, new Comparator<UserContribution>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(UserContribution o1, UserContribution o2) {
        return o1.date.after(o2.date) ? -1 : o1.date.before(o2.date) ? 1 : 0;
    }
});
```

`userContributions` ends up with 3 items in it.  A breakpoint set in the `compare` method is not getting hit (and Android Studio is showing it as not a valid breakpoint) and thus my items aren't getting sorted.  Why come?

Thanks!

Comment: "Why come?" Idk why I came...

Comment: Apparently the code *is* being called (I just changed the sense of the compare, and the items are now in reverse order from what they were).  But why is the breakpoint broken?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest avoiding the nested ternary operation, or delegating the `compare` method to the class being compared. This makes the code more readable, helps avoid potential ordering errors in the comparison, and will allow you to insert breakpoints in each branch to see the result of the comparison.

#### Option 1: Full conditional structure

```
public int compare(UserContributions o1, UserContributions o2) {
    if (o1.date.after(o2)) {
        return 1;
    else if (o1.date.before(o2)) {
        return -1;
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Note this is an error prone method because you are reliant on `date.before()` and `date.after()` correctly mimicking the operations `<` and `>`. I personally prefer Option 2.

#### Option 2: Delegate comparison to dates

```
public int compare(UserContributions o1, UserContributions o2) {
    return o1.date.compareTo(o2.date);
}
```

Note the `date.compare()` method would take care of defining a comparison of dates.

Comment: I actually did try Option 1, hoping that would solve my breakpoint problem; it did not.  I ended up changing the code to Option 2 (even before you suggested it), but still, that did nothing to solve the breakpoint problem. Thanks, though.  The code is still being call–I reversed the sense of the sort and saw the items rearrange themselves–but no joy with the breakpoint (although it's kind of a moot point now).  Other, numerous breakpoints are working just fine.  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯